# Custom fields in MongoDB query result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After being so used to SQL, I have came across this problem with mongoDB.
First, I am using mongoose.

Now, the problem. I have a collection named `User`.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema ({
    id : ObjectId,
    name : {type : String, trim : true, required : true},
    email: {type:String, trim:true, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    password: {type:String, required: true, set: passwordToMD5},
    age: {type:Number, min: 18, required: true, default: 18},
    gender: {type: Number, default:0, required: true},

    height: {type: Number, default:180, min: 140, max: 220},
    _eye_color: {type: ObjectId, default: null},
    location: {
            lon: {type: Number, default: 0},
            lat: {type: Number, default: 0}
    },
    status: {type:Number, required: true, default:0}
    },{
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        collection:"user"});
```

Now I need to select all users from this collection and sort them by special attribude (say "rank"). This rank is calculated with certain logic depending of their distance from a point, age compared with given age, etc...

So now I was wondering how to select this rank and then use it in sorting? I have tried to use virtuals, they are handy to count additional info, but unfortunately, it is not possible to sort the `find()` results by a virtual field. 
Of course I can calculate this rank in a virtual, then select all records, and after that, in callback, do some javascript. But in this case, as I select all the users then sort and then limit, the javascript part might take too long...
I was thinking to use **mapreduce**, but I am not sure it will do what I want.
Can someone give me a hint if my task is possible to do in **mongoDB/mongoose**?

**EDIT 1**

I have also tried to use aggregation framework, and at first it seemed to be the best solution with the `$project` ability. But then, when I needed to do rank calculations, I found out that aggregation does not support a lot of mathematical functions like `sin`, `cos` and `sqrt`. And also it was impossible to use pre-defined usual javascript functions in projection. I mean,the function got called, but I was not able to pass current record fields to it.

```
{$project: {
  distance_from_user: mUtils.getDistance(point, this.location)
}
```

Inside function the second attr was "undefined".

So I guess it is impossible to do my rank calculations with aggregation framework.

**EDIT 2**
Ok, I know everyone tells me not to use mapreduce as it is not good for realtime queries, but as I cannot use aggregation, I think I'll try mapreduce. So Let's say I have this map reduce.

```
function map() {
            emit(1, // Or put a GROUP BY key here
                {name: this.name, // the field you want stats for
                    age: this.age,
                    lat: this.location.lat,
                    lon: this.location.lon,
                    distance:0,
                    rank:0

                });
        }

        function reduce(key, values) {


            return val;
        }

        function finalize(key, value){

            return value;
        }


        var command = {'mapreduce': "user", 'map': map.toString(), 'reduce': reduce.toString(), query:{$and: [{gender: user_params.gender}, {_id: {$ne: current_user_id}}]}, 'out': {inline:1}};

        mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand(command, function(error, result){
            if(error) {
                log(error);
                return;
            }
            log(result);
            return;
        });
```

What should I write in reduce (or maybe change map) to calculate rank for every user?

Comment: You shouldn't use mapreduce for 'real time' queries. Take a look at the aggregation framework http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: I have tried the aggregation, but in aggregation framework it is not possible to use the functions I need for rank calculation. For example there is no `sqrt()`, `sin()`, `cos()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real solution is to calculate your rank for each document and storing it in the document. Since this value will be constant as long as the values in your document remain constant you can simply calculate this value whenever you update the fields that affect it.

Map/reduce certainly isn't a good solution for this nor is any other type of aggregation. Precalculating your rank and storing it with the document is the only option that scales if you're using MongoDB.

Comment: I cannot calculate and store results, because the calculations are done regarding to a logged in user details. So this ranking is different for every user of the system.

Comment: I guess the only other alternative is a mapreduce running periodically to generate the rank?

Comment: @ArVan Why is that a problem? Calculate the rank every time the user logs in or at any other appropriate time. Aggregating over the entire dataset continuously is not a scalable solution to your problem.

Comment: I need to get this ranked list on demand. when user opens certain screen. 
And I have problems with mapreduce I guess. I don't quiet understand haw to make it generade the rank when nothing needs to be reduced... Can you give me some help with that? Let's say the rank should be calculated as follows: 
`rank = this.location.lat+this.location.lat*(this.age > age+1)?4:5`.

Comment: @Remon van Vliet, you want me to store all possible ranked list for all users? Let's say I have 10000 users, then for every one of them I need to store 9999 records? then update those records on every login?

Comment: then this ranking should be really realtime. I mean the user might login then leave the app for a long time during which he/she might change their location, so the pre-stored values of rank for him/her would be not correct as I need to use the user's location i ranking logic.

Comment: @ArVan No, I don't expect that since that obviously doesn't scale either. I thought a rank was stable per user. Map/reduce isn't the tool you need for this since you're not actually doing an m/r. The aggregation framework can do what you need but I'm not sure about the performance. You might have to conclude MongoDB isn't a solution that fits your needs very well and/or that you need to rework your application to get the rank in a more efficient way. It's a little beyond the Q&A scope of SO.

Comment: Thanks @Remon van Vliet, I came to that conclusion already. Unfortunately I can't change neither the db nor the ranking logic on my own, ned conversation with a client :) Thanks anyway. Finally I understood mongo :D

Comment: @ArVan Fair enough. Note that even in an RDBMS such as MySQL what you would want to do would actually still be very heavyweight. It's just that SQL allows you to do those things natively but under the hood it's still an N^M problem. You may have to rethink the whole ranking bit and find some similar solution that is easier or faster to (pre)calculate. That basically means going back to the functional requirements of the system as a whole and see if you can achieve similar results with a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are aware of amount of computations such thing would need - if you'd do it every time user logs in, you'll have interesting load peaks when lots of people would log in at shorter amount of time - and your page (interface) would be heavily resources-bound (which is not good).
I'd recommend you something a bit different - keeping ranking for every logged-on user and updating them in intervals: keeping "short session" and "long session" (long session - the one you use in web browser and short - "online, currently using the site") and generating ranks regularly only for "shortly-active" users and rarely for the logged on in the long session. Something like every five minutes. Much more scallable - and if user would be unhappy about him not having his rank counted - you may always tweak the sys to count his ranks on demand.
You might use mapredurce in such case - your map function should only emit the data you need for counting the rank for a given user (like age, lat, long, whatever you need) AND a result (rank) for a tested user (emit it empty). For reduce function you'd need to look at sorting with mapreduce (it highly depends on the way you create the rank) - also you'd count the rank (or some kind of a sub-value) for the other users.

Comment: This solution would result in a significantly higher consumption of resources than any on-demand calculation. You're very likely to recalculate ranks for the same users without any of the values changing that would affect the rank. Additionally load peaks shouldn't be an issue if it's functionally allowed to do the rank calculation asynchronously (you'd simply queue the recalcs and they'd take longer if there are peaks which is exactly the performance pattern you want).

Comment: It all depends - if the page is often used and computations might get resource-heavy, it's much better to keep the amount of computations at given period of time controllable - It might be creating it on-demand with some kind of caching or using something like time-based computation which is defaultly not done on demand. I'd discourage doing everything on request, as it might get totally unscallable.

Comment: You can apply the same throttling rules to on-demand asynchronous workload queueing as you can to periodic workloads. Load predictability is definitely an important factor but I'd assume the predictability is already limited if we're talking about load peaks. Note that on-demand is how almost every system that has to deal with peak logins for example do it because it auto balances itself (slower logins/larger login queues -> less on demand computation) and allows for easier throttling (e.g. login queues, etc. See pretty much every large gaming service out there).

Answer (score 0):

It look like a good use case for [MongoDB + Hadoop](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop+Quick+Start).

This [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/spf13/mongodb-and-hadoop) show some of the possibilities of this combination.

Comment: hmmm... I think it is not possible to use with **node.js**

Comment: If you use it with the [batch aggregation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop+Scenarios) scenario, node.js should not have to interact with hadoop. You will have to write your mapreduce in Java though. Some [examples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/examples) are on github.